# How to create a new column with .size() values of other column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

```
 df2 = df_cleaned.groupby('company').size()
 df2.columns = ['company', 'frequency']
 #df2.sort_values('frequency') # error : No axis named frequency for object type <class 'type'>
 df2
```

I have a dataframe "df_cleaned" with a 'company' column and im trying to create a new dataframe "df2" with a extra 'frequency' column to check how many times each company has been mentioned. I am unable to create a new frequency column. Seems like i'm doing something wrong, please help me out.

[Screenshot showing no frequency column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6dtK.png)

Comment: `df2 = df_cleaned['company'].value_counts().reset_index(name='frequency')`

Comment: Thanks Hoang that worked like magic !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df2 = df_cleaned.groupby('company').size().to_frame('frecuency')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide the data for us, so generate it:

```
import numpy as np
source = ['3Com', '3M', 'A-T-O', 'A.H. Robins']
cmp = [source[i] for i in np.random.randint(4, size = 20)]
df = pd.DataFrame(cmp, columns = ['company'])

Out[1]:
    company
0   A.H. Robins
1   3M
2   A.H. Robins
3   A.H. Robins
4   3M
5   3M
6   3Com
7   A-T-O
8   3Com
9   A-T-O
10  3M
11  3M
12  A-T-O
13  3M
14  3M
15  A.H. Robins
16  A-T-O
17  A-T-O
18  A-T-O
19  3Com

df.groupby('company')[['company']].count().rename(columns = {'company':'frequency'})

Out[2]:

        frequency
company 
3Com        3
3M          7
A-T-O       6
A.H. Robins 4
```

Comment: yeah my bad, Thank you very much.